# How to EasyMock the Class.method.method

Tags: mocking, mockito, easymock

Required to Mock class.method.method ,Given the example below 
It's always giving Null pointer Exception.

expect(
                EasyMock.mock(TBXClient.class).getStatus().getMessage()).andReturn("check");

Can anyone help me to resolve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no mock chaining. The result of `getStatus` should also be a mock on which you will mock `getMessage` and then everything will work as expected

```
TBXClient client = mock(TBXClient.class);
Status status = mock(Status.class);
expect(client.getStatus()).andReturn(status);
expect(status.getMessage()).andReturn("check");
replay(client, status);
```

However, `Status` looks a lot like a value type, so it probably doesn't need to be mocked. In this case, I would just do.

```
TBXClient client = mock(TBXClient.class);
expect(client.getStatus()).andReturn(Status.CHECK);
replay(client, status);
```